# ExpandableListView, как загружать данные в асинхронном потоке?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, expandablelistview

Имею ViewPager на несколько, на каждой его страничке ExpandableListView который нужно наполнить данными, данные наполняются весьма долго поэтому решил вывести в параллельный поток. Пробовал сделать через AsyncTask передавая в него экземпляры массивов для ExpandableListView и pagenumber для ViewPager, но в итоге данные отображаются в совершенно хаотичном порядке. 
Я в андройде новичок, подскажите как обычно решаются такие задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Миллион тыщ раз уже обсуждалось.

Паттерн следующий:

1. Данные асинхронно (то есть либо через `Service` либо через
   `AsyncTask` или для любителей хардкора через `Runnable`) складываем
   в БД SQLite
2. Над SQLite пишем `ContentProvider` c `CursorLoader`
3. Далее организуем подпитку списка через `CursorAdapter`